# How does the "recommended deletion" system work?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Recently a question got two very similar answers. Both got flagged for deletion, and in both cases the community agreed that deletion was the right course of action, but the system deleted only one.

Why?

The two reviews:

- [Deleted](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/9897)
- [Non-deleted](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/9922)

For what I understand ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145287/is-recommend-deletion-secretly-a-vote-to-delete/145292#145292)), if six persons with no deletion rights (but with review ones) "recommend deletion", the system should automatically delete the post. Why this did not happen here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked our community team and got pointed to [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/answers-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-in-review-should-not-be-undeletable) which explains that if the poster casts an undelete vote, it is treated as a disputed review and a flag is raised for moderator attention instead of automatically deleting the post.

That's exactly what happened in the second example. Everyone in the review queue recommended deletion, but the poster disagreed, which raised a flag. I've handled that flag now by turning the answer into a comment.